# Postgres Dump Excluding Corrupted Page Block

Tags: postgresql, psql, dump, corruption

I Tried to take a dump of my database. While Dumping i received the below error. I knew a table in my database is corrupted and i can use exclude option to exclude the corrupted table and take dump of the remaining tables. But I am searching for an option to dump even the corrupted table excluding the invalid page blocks.

The command i used to take dump is :

```
pg_dump -U postgres -p 5432 -d DBNAME -v -n SCHEMA_NAME -f "OUTFILE.sql"
```

The error prints:

```
 pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "TABLE_NAME" failed: PQgetResult() failed.
    pg_dump: Error message from server: ERROR:  invalid page in block 2145280 of relation base/16384/25464
```

I was able to access the corrupted table and its data. So i believe the part of the data which i can access can be dumped. Kindly share if there is any possibility to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set `zero_damaged_pages = on`, then PostgreSQL should zero (and ignore) such pages.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I had two scenarios where i faced corruption. The first one i tried  pg_resetxlog.exe because i was not able to start posgres. But after that i faced issues in dumping the database so i did exactly what you are suggesting zero_damaged_pages = on but even after that i was not able to take dump so i have to manually add the tables that are corrupted in the --exclude-table option.

Comment: `zero_damaged_pages` will only complain if the block *header* is corrupt. But the error message looks like that. `pg_resetxlog` will damage your cluster, yes. If you cannot start PostgreSQL, look for the reason in the log.

Comment: PostgreSQL Documentation says "This function is sometimes needed if these files have become corrupted. It should be used only as a last resort, when the server will not start due to such corruption." So i tried using pg_resetxlog after this i was able to start postgres and access the database but still the dump process failed on the corrupted table.

Comment: You use `pg_resetxlog` only if you already *know* that the cluster is damaged. What was the reason PostgreSQL couldn't start in the first place?

Comment: Accidentally the machine was shutdown when there were so many operations happening in the DB. Immediately after starting the machine I  am facing this issue,. This occurs randomly and not every time say once in 100 times even for the restart case. And one more thing how to confirm that the cluster is damaged. The version i am using is 9.6.1 and i read a release note from psql that 9.6.12 is the stable one released with many bug fixes one of it address a corruption issue. Whether upgrade will fix my issue.

Comment: IN pg_log
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "Database.schema.table_name".
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT ERROR:  canceling autovacuum task
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "Database.schema.table_nam"
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-01-29 13:43:50 GMT FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command

Comment: Of course you should keep applying bug fixes (though I see no indication that this would be a database bug). The log looks like a clean shutdown. The interesting log entries would be where the database tries to start but fails. I mean *before* you currupted it by running `pg_resetxlog`.

Comment: Do you mean pg_resetlog is the reason for the corruption ? .. Is there any common reason for the starting issue.

Comment: Yes, `pg_resetxlog` can corrupt your cluster. That's why you only run it if your database cannot be brought up any other way.